# need to find invalid xml parts

Tags: xml

I got a error with opening a xml, it's only very unclear.

> it points to 857:564, whatever that is (XMLEditor). An invalid XML
>   character (Unicode 0x12)

I only can't find out what unicode 0x12 is.

It seems that the amperstand gives a problem, atm i have this:

```
<to>
  <person email="w@bewitched.com" name="M & L Wattenberg"/>
</to>
```

would this be better?

```
<to>
  <person email="w@bewitched.com">M & L Wattenberg</person>
</to>
```

Or won't that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't help. `&` is a special character in XML, and should be replaced with `&amp;` It doesn't matter if it's in an attribute or in  a text node.

See the definition of character data [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml11-20040204/#dt-chardata). (Note the rule about apostrophes and double quotes in attributes, it's another typical pitfall of dealing with XML data.)

Although you didn't specify the programming language that you're using to produce the XML, in pretty much every XML handling library there is usually a way to do all the necessary escaping without having to do it manually.

Comment: `Invalid entity: `&amp L Wattenberg"/>`
It seems &amp is not allowed in a entity at all.
(i use processing btw, which is a dialect of java)

Comment: Note the semicolon at the end: `&amp;` and not just `&amp`.