# XML parsing error

Tags: java, xml, regex

I am getting org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x12) was found in the element content of the document. error on the client side. Can someone tell what is the regular expression using java.util.regex.Pattern to replace such characters so that I can exclude in the server side.

tried..

Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\0012");

but didn't work

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148145/need-to-find-invalid-xml-parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to look for some literal string with stuff in it that the regex parser is likely to have trouble with, use Pattern.quote() around the literal.

Also, you're using an octal encoding, not a unicode one - you forgot the u after \.

In this case:

> Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("\u0012"));

Note: I haven't tried this particular case!

Comment: @java1977 I thought it probably would, but I so often forget about regex specifics that I reach for quote() whenever there's any question.  It's faster to write than to read everything, and unlike me, never makes mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Most "control characters" (<32 ASCII) are not legal in XML 1.0. Some of them *are* legal in XML 1.1. If your users expect them to be supported, you may want to make sure you're using a parser which can handle the newer Recommendation.